# Wiremock webhook and response won't return same random value

Tags: wiremock-standalone

I am using wiremock-standalone-3.4.2, trying to emulate a 3rd party that upon a request from me responds with a certain field with UUID value X and sends the same value X to a webhook. The value X needs to change from request to request so it needs to be randomized. I can't seem to find a way to have the emulator return in the response the same random value it send to the webhook. Any ideas?

Tried using `{{randomValue type='UUID'}}` in both places but this expectedly resulted in 2 different random values. -

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/v1/businesses"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {
      "id": "{{randomValue type='UUID'}}"
}},
"serveEventListeners": [
    {
      "name": "webhook",
      "parameters": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "http://some-url/",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        "body": "{\"id\": \"{{randomValue type='UUID'}}\"}"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do this natively WireMock. We do have a [proposal to implement this exact thing](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/2359) but at the moment it hasn't been addressed.  I think there are a number of ways to achieve this at the moment:

1. Pass the UUID into the request (as a header for example) and then this would be available in the response and the webhook
2. Use the [WireMock State Extension](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-state-extension) to add the generated UUID to shared state and then this would be available in the response and the webhook